# How to have/handle electronic signatures in meteorjs via input textbox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am interested in using "electronic signatures" in my application. Think healthcare.gov when you "sign" your input at the end of typing in all your information by typing your name into a textbox and clicking "submit". Something tells me there is more to this "digital signature" than just taking your text input from the input text field and persisting it into some database. Can anyone shed some light on this? Are there libraries that handle this sort of thing?

Comment: Note: This question is really more of legal nature than software. It completely depend on legal definition of "digital signature" for your type of documents.

Comment: It is software. Using healthcare.gov as an example, you have a textbox after you fill in your information where you "type your full name" then click "Sign". This is software.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase - There is no abstract concept of "signature" - i.e. you are "signing" your accepting of TOU on many sites by simple checkbox or just performing any action, to the other extreme one may need to crypto-sign image of document with private key stored on hardware key storage device. It completely depend on what "signature" needed for your document/contract (and that better to be discussed with lawyers) - so there is no generic "signature" library (do your really need one to check checkbox?)